# How to center an box inside a AppBar in React with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with Material UI and attempting to create a responsive navigation bar using Material UI in a React app. I'm having trouble centering the Box when the device size is small enough. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
  <AppBar elevation={1} position="sticky" sx={{background: 'rgb(255 255 255)', py: "10px"}}>
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
            <Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{height: 80, width: 80, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },}} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo}/>
            {/**Appear on Tablet and phone**/}
            <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
                <IconButton
                    size="large"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                    color="#000000"
                >
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                    id="menu-appbar"
                    anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'bottom',
                        horizontal: 'left',
                    }}
                    keepMounted
                    transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'top',
                        horizontal: 'left',
                    }}
                    open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                    onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                    sx={{
                        display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
                        background: 'trasparent'
                    }}
                >
                {pages.map((page, index) => (
                    <MenuItem key={index} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                        <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
                </Menu>
            </Box>
            {/**Image appear on Tablet and phone and is supposed to be at center**/}
            <Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{height: 80, width: 80, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo}/>
            {/**Appear on Desktop**/}
            <Tabs aria-label="visible arrows tabs example" sx={{marginLeft: '5px', marginRight: '5px', width: 'auto', display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }}} value={tabValue} onChange={handleTabChange} indicatorColor='#162667'>
                <Tab sx={{fontSize: '12px'}} label="Home"/>
                <Tab sx={{fontSize: '12px'}} label="Find a Store"/>
                <Tab sx={{fontSize: '12px'}} label="How To Avail Offer"/>
                <Tab sx={{fontSize: '12px'}} label="T & C"/>
                <Tab sx={{fontSize: '12px'}} label="Contact Us"/>
            </Tabs> 
            <Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{width: 110, ml: 'auto', display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },}} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo2}/>
        </Toolbar>
    </Container>
</AppBar>
```

The part that needs to be centered is this one:

```
<Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{height: 80, width: 80, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo}/>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the logo doesn't appear centered on tablet and phone devices as intended. What am I missing? How can I properly center the logo on smaller devices?

Answer (score 0):

For me you are limiting the box to 80px, if you change the width like this, it should work.

```
<Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{height: 80, width: "100%", display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo}/>
```

-- UPDATE --

Check if this works for you.
I added position: 'absolute' to the hamburger icon box and mx: 'auto' to the logo box.

```
<Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none', position: 'absolute' } }}>
<IconButton
    size="large"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
    color="#000000"
>
    <MenuIcon />
</IconButton>
<Menu
    id="menu-appbar"
    anchorEl={anchorElNav}
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'left',
    }}
    keepMounted
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left',
    }}
    open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
    onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
    sx={{
        display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
        background: 'trasparent'
    }}
>
    {pages.map((page, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
            <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Menu>
</Box>
<Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{ height: 80, width: 80, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mx: 'auto' }} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo} />
```

Comment: if i do that, the image would stretch

Comment: try to close it in another box that use 100% width.

<Box sx={{ width: '100%', display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },}}>
                <Box onClick={() => undefined} sx={{height: 80, width: 80, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} component="img" alt="Your logo." src={logo}/>
            </Box>

Comment: there is a hamburger icon on the left. If i put it in another Box and `justififyContent: center`, it will not center properly